# Get abbreviation from Java TimeZone?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, date

I need to get the Abbreviation(as String) for the existing Java TimeZone Object. Is there any way to do this without direct mapping ?

```
Eg- TimeZone     -  ("America/Los_Angeles") 
    Abbreviation -  PDT
```

Comment: `PDT` or `PST`?

Comment: TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")
                   .getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);

Comment: @user1241241 I recommend you don’t use `TimeZone`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZoneId` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Alright, Noted..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for this:

```
String s = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")
                   .getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
```

Comment: Eugene, when the question is tagged java8 (and even if it wasn’t), please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and poorly designed `TimeZone` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `ZoneId`.

Comment: @OleV.V. u mean something like `String s = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")
                         .getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.US);`?

Comment: The output of this is "GMT-08:00" (at least when I run it), which doesn't answer the question. It also can't take into account standard/daylight time for different dates.

Answer (score 15):

### java.time

I suggest that the abbreviation you want for `America/Los_Angeles` would be `PT` for *Pacific Time*. This name and this abbreviation can be used all year regardless of summer time (DST). By contrast `PDT` is for *Pacific Daylight Time* so is used during summer only.

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");

    System.out.println("Summer time neutral abbreviation: "
            + zone.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH));
```

Output:

> Summer time neutral abbreviation: PT

If you want the abbreviation relevant for this part of year only (standard time or summer time):

```
    DateTimeFormatter zoneAbbreviationFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println("Current abbreviation for either standard or summer time: "
            + ZonedDateTime.now(zone).format(zoneAbbreviationFormatter));
```

Output when running in May:

> Current abbreviation for either standard or summer time: PDT

Please substitute your desired locale. For many locales it will not make any difference, but some time zones have localized abbreviations for some locales.