# Get Current TimeZone Abbrevation Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, timezone

Is there any library that I can get the current timezone abbrevation for Android like in this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations

For example, I am in Turkey and the timezone abbrevation for Turkey is TRT and I want to display it to user?
Here is the code I used so far:

```
fun getTimeZoneAbbrevation():String {
val id = TimeZone.getDefault().id
return ZoneId.of(id).getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH)  }
```

And the result I get from this function is "Europe/Istanbul", what I except is TRT.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56183335/2827025

Comment: I tried these solutions, but didn't work for me :(

Comment: In this case, it would be helpful to add the code you used so that others can help you.

Comment: Now, I edited my question, thank you :)!

Comment: FYI, those abbreviations are ***not* real time zones**, not standardized, and are not unique! For date-time work, use real time zone names in format of `Continent/Region` such as `Europe/Istanbul`.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yeah, but obviously the person who is asking the question is only looking for a solution in the form of an abbreviation, regardless of whether or not it's a real time zone. I don't really understand the point of this comment.

Comment: Funnily from your code I get `EET` on my Java 8. So an abbreviation, but not the one you asked for (EET is probably for Eastern European Time).

Comment: On Java 15 I do get `TRT` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

**This should work:**

```
    val zone = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).zone
    println(zone.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH))
```

**When I input Europe/Istanbul I get TRT:**

```
    val zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Istanbul")
    println(zone.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH))
```

[image]

**It would be extremely strange if the code wouldn't work on your system.**

I have changed my default time zone to Istanbul and I am getting TRT when running the first block of code:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. *It would be extremely strange if the code wouldn't work on your system.* In that case the situation is extremely strange. What the OP does seems to be effectively the same as you do. The short display name is taken from the locale data. Locale data differs between desktop Java and Android and between Java versions.

Comment: We have observed a difference (if the OP is to be believed, I don’t see why not in this case). I have also observed a difference between Java 8 and Java 15 on my computer (see my comments under the question).

Comment: @OleV.V. Alright, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers! But in Android, it still prints Europe/Istanbul. But you are right, in IntelliJ it display TRT. I think it is different for Android.

Comment: @AbdulsametKılınçarslan Interesting, you seem to be right.